Hitting time Probability when random walk is conditioned to return to $0$.
Suppose $(S_{k})_{k=1}^{2n}$ is a simple symmetric random walk started at $0$ and conditioned to return to $0$ after $2n$ steps.
Let for an integer $a>0$, $E_{a}$ be the event that the level $a$ is hit by the walk.
Then I want to find the probability $P(E_{a})$.
My attempt:-
I know that there should be $n$ exactly positive steps and $n$ negative steps for $S_{2n}=0$.
So the total sample paths of the walk can be $\binom{2n}{n}$ and I can guess that this should be the denominator of $P(E_{a})$.
However, I don't see the number of ways how to arrange the $n$ positive and $n$ negative steps so that the level $a$ is hit.

what you did was indeed correct, the total sample paths of the walk can be $\binom{2n}{n}$
instead of finding this(which is the numerator for our answer)the number of ways how to arrange the $n$ positive and $n$ negative steps so that the level $a$ is hit. we can find the complementary set for this and subtract this from 1.... because finding the number of ways of the complementary set is easy
Finding the number of ways for the complementary set(here I am using reflection principle,visit:https://math.mit.edu/~dws/iap/iap04.pdf for better understanding)
the number of paths that never reach level $(a)$  is the same as the number of paths that never reach level - $(a)$.This is equivalent to the number of paths that go up to $2a$ but without getting below $0$
we can represent such pairs as $$\binom{2n}{n}-\binom{2n}{n-a}$$
here $\binom{2n}{n-a}$ represent the number of paths that reach or exceed level as you can see
so... that's all we can just use this as the numerator and the
final result  $P(E_{a})$ is equal to$$1-\frac{\binom{2n}{n-a}}{\binom{2n}{n}}$$

The number of paths that never hit level $a$ is simply the total number of paths minus those that do hit level $a$

The link you provided was very useful. Thanks!. I think what you want to say is that the number of paths which hits $a$ and return to $0$ at time $2n$ is same as the number of paths which hit $a$ and goes to level $2a$ at time $2n$ due to the reflection principle. The latter of which is counted by $\binom{2n}{(2n+2a)/2}=\binom{2n}{n+a}$.

BINGO! What you have written is correct(the key concept here is principle reflection,if we are okay with that we can crush this question)
